# How can I format a date in RFC format?

Tags: c#, .net, date, formatting

I need to format a date in RFC format for an RSS feed.  I have tried taking my date and adding the following:

```
.ToString("ddd, dd mm yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
```

However it seems this is not valid.  Any help would be great!  The end result I need is, for example, Mon, 01 Jan 2013 GMT

Comment: Are you sure you're not reinventing the wheel? There's an entire namespace dedicated to [Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx) that has all kinds of formatting already built in.

Comment: It seems that was exactly what I was doing, I didn't realise this as I am relatively new to asp.net as a whole.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing because your example lacks any time (but has a time-zone).
Nevertheless, try using `MMM` for month:

```
.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
```

If you don't want time, simply omit that section from the string:

```
.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy")
```

But since you mentioned you're generating a string for an RSS feed, you could just use [the "R" format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123) to generate a RFC1123-format date / time string:

```
.ToString("R")
```

Comment: Tiny addition - Its worth adding that _mm_ in a datetime format string gives you minutes, not month. An important and hard to test distinction. Make sure you get it right! I've seen this issue in data display code that only blew up a few days in a month, if the feature was used.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, and sorry about the poor example, I did intend to include the time but it had been a long day and was gone 2am lol.  Thanks again